# Sparklines in R for use in Latex table (using Knitr)

Tags: r, knitr, sparktable

I would like to create a sparkline using R and include it in a Latex table (using knitr) .

I have found the SparkTable package but have been unable to work out how to specify (based on my own set of rules) which data points are classified as "outliers".

Effectively, I only want to colour the last data point (either Red, Blue, Grey, or no colour) (based on a custom rule).  In addition, I would like to specify the limits for the y-axis and for the image to look similar to the following,

[image]

Any help / suggestions will be much appreciated

Thanks,
Marie

Answer (score 0):

I should have read the manual in more detail - apologies. Page 20 of the version April 20, 2015

• if type==’allColors’: a character vector of length 6 (including NA’s) containing
colors. The elements of the color vector are used as:

- first element: color for minimal value
- second element: color for maximal value
- third element: color for last value
- fourth element:color for filling
- fifth element: color for the line
- sixth element: color for interquartil range